# Kali screen flickering after upgrade

Tags: linux, kali-linux, debian

I am running `kali 5.4.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1kali1 (2020-02-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux` / Dual Boot with Windows 10

I get a glitch on the screen after running 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade' the first time after installing this OS.

My PC is:

```
OS: Kali GNU/Linux 
Host: HP Laptop 15 
Kernel: 5.4.0-kali4
Packages: 3197 (dpkg)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.300GHz 
GPU: AMD Radeon RX Vega 10
Memory: 1053MiB / 9944MiB
```

[image: here is the capture of my screen]

I've been struggling to solve this issue, hope you can help

Comment: upgrade the video driver

Comment: Hmmm, might want to try **apt-get update** then **apt-get upgrade** or **dist-upgrade**. Although it's probably going to be faster if you save your files and format with a newer rolling release.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with my nVidia 940m on Debian. Everytime I tired to move something on screen, screen gone mad and turned into a broken CRT.

On IRC channels of Debian, fellow friends suggested me to upgrade the **"kernel itself".** But there was nothing to upgrade, my system was up to date.

Aaaaand they talked about "backports" repos. That kernel update from backports saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the screen flickering. I had only a black flickering screen with no desktop. It turned out dpkg was interrupted and my upgrade had not completed.

I had to run the following command to complete it and resolve the issue:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and here is the solution bro:

You can disable XFCE Window compositor in Settings/Window Manager Tweaks/Compositor => Click disable

But For a permanent solution, I did this in terminal (maybe you'll need to reboot, but I did not needed)

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -t string -s "xpresent" --create
pkill xfwm
```

And voila :)